# Why is Google Analytics event not sent from onSubmit?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-analytics, form-submit

I'd like to track how often users download files using Analytics' events, but even though the events seem to have been sent, the tracking .gif doesn't seem to be arriving properly.

To download files, users are required to fill out a brief form. The information entered into this form is checked by the function `checkSubmit()` (which returns `false` when the entered info is invalid or incomplete, `true` when the information is good to be submitted). Once submitted, the user is redirected to the file.

```
<script>
function checkSubmit() {
    …
    if(dataIsGood) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', 'the_filename.xxx']);
        return true;    //allow the form to submit
    } else {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'info not okay']);
        return false;   //keep the form from being submitted
    }
}
</script>

<form action="/form/emailcaptureform" method="post" onSubmit="return checkSubmit();">
… </form>
```

In the Chrome console, the [Google Analytics Tracking Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) says Download event tracking beacons have been sent, but the console says it **failed to load resource __utm.gif**

This happens ***only* with events pushed just before the form is submitted**. **Events work elsewhere** on my site—including the Form event pushed when the form info is no good (in the `else` block above)

The [Analytics snippet](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html#Snippet) seems to be working, accepting `_trackPageview`s and `_trackEvent`s.

**The request URL for __utm.gif is well-formed**: copy-and-pasting the URL from the gadebug output into the location bar returns __utm.gif without a hitch.

The event is pushed without issue when pushed from another element. For example:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', the_filename.xxx']);">Event!</a>
```

Pushing the event, pausing for a few seconds, then returning `true` does not seem to have any effect—beyond adding a pause before submitting the form.

Do you have solutions or suggestions?

Comment: Seems there's a conflict between the <form> submission and Analytics' dealing with the event: the event is not registering because it needs to make a successful GET request and this GET request is being interrupted by the <form>'s POST request. Any idea how to resolve this conflict?

Comment: The ways to work around this conflict of requests are 1) to submit the form data asynchronously or 2) to interrupt the submit event on the form, hold it until the GA event is processed, then have GA allow the form submission to occur.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is single threaded. When you execute `_gaq.push`, you are pushing something on to a queue to be handled later. However your code returns `true` before 'later' comes, and the GA code never gets to execute (because the next action is to go to the next page).

I'd suggest that this may be an appropriate moment to use traditional or synchronous tracking with [`._trackEvent`](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiEventTracking.html)