# Does Google Analytics event tracking on links slow down the user experience?

Tags: performance, google-analytics, event-tracking

I am considering attaching onclick events to internal links on my site to do some Google Analytics event tracking. But I am concerned about performance. My understanding is that the workflow will change:

1. User clicks on hyperlink
2. A call is made to Google Analytics to send event tracking data
3. Browser waits for response from GA server
4. Browser follows the link and opens the new page.

I am concerned about the delay introduced by steps 2 and 3. So the questions are:

1. Is my understanding of the flow correct?
2. What's the typical delay (in milliseconds) that the call to GA event tracking introduces?

Answer (score 3):

Event tracking works by making an image request from the Google servers. A problem is that following a link to a new URL stops any pending/in-progress requests.If the browser is opening a link to a new URL in the same window before the tracking request has been made, you can loose analytics data.

So step 3 isn't a wait, but a delay that has to be added in to allow the tracking image request to complete (or at least start). 100-150 milliseconds is long enough for the request, but short enough not to be noticed by users.

I use some variation of the following event tracking code (jQuery code):

```
$('.someClassForTracking').click(function(e){
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action, ...]);
  if (this.target != '_blank') {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.href;
    setTimeout(function(){location.href = url}, 150);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Google doesn't ask us to do anything like this to manually introduce delays to make their tracking work. So I'm assuming GA's JS does that automatically. Would you happen to have documentation on this where people are asked to introduce setTimeout delays?

Comment: Google describes using a delay with event tracking for outbound links  at http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920 ...

Comment: Thanks. I just found it and was about to edit my comment :) I have also seen a variation that doesn't use setTimeout but _gaq.push(function(){ document.location = href; });. Seems cleaner to me.

Comment: Interesting... I'm assuming that GA creates an img element and sets the src to some URL... So with the non setTimeout version, I'm wondering if it works because GA is checking if the image has loaded, or if going through the _gaq.push code adds enough instructions to give the img time to load. In that case you might get inconsistent tracking results.

Comment: If what you're saying is right and GA is creating an img element and setting the src to send the data then it doesn't have to wait for the response. The need is only to send the data one way - from client to server. It can get to the next element in the queue immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hitCallback` mechanism, which is documented for `analytics.js` but is also available for `ga.js`.

This was addressed on another question: [Track event in google analytics upon clicking form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086587/track-event-in-google-analytics-upon-clicking-form-submit)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'hitCallback' which fires once the tracking is done at GA's end. Don't worry about timeouts, as this event will fire if GA takes long time to get back with a response - in short it handles event timeouts.

```
<script>
/**
* Function that tracks a click on an outbound link in Google Analytics.
* This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string
* as the event label.
*/
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {'hitCallback':
     function () {
     document.location = url;
     }
   });
}
</script>
```

You'll also need to add (or modify) the onclick attribute to your links. Use this example as a model for your own links:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick=”trackOutboundLink(‘http://www.example.com’); return false;">Check out example.com</a>
```

Taken from here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented GA before, both internally and externally and not seen a noticeable difference in performance.  Additionally, I believe the latest method of tracking link clicks allows for the tracking to be done asynchronously.

[Collections- Google Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/)

Adding tracking in this manner will allow the user to follow the link action while the tracking is done asynchronously.

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'myLink', 'clicked'])"
```

Comment: Thanks but I think you're mistaken about the async tracking. The advantage that async tracking offers is it uses the _gaq array to store the events in a queue, which means even if the GA javascript has not yet been loaded and the user performs an action that you want to track, you can still do it. However, for anything to be tracked a call has to be made to GA's servers and all the on-page data from _gaq has to be sent over to Google. My assumption is that GA's JS introduces some sort of document.unload handler that delays the unloading of the document until all the info has been sent to GA.

Comment: @tinkerr -- I'd be very interested if you find any confirmation about GA using some kind of unload handler... seems like the logical way of doing things!