# Jquery Analytics tracking onclick NS_BINDING_ABORTED

Tags: jquery, analytics, webtrends

Hey I am adding an onclick event to track clicks on certain videos, the 3rd party tool we are using is webtrends.

I am adding the onclick event and it works fine. The thing to note is the url in the link makes the user browse to a different url.

When I track the onclick event in httpfox I see the error NS_BINDING_ABORTED.

My jquery

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
$j('a.wt_video').click(function (e) {
    var title = ($j(this).attr("title"));
    if (title.length != 0) {
        handleDynamicVideoWebTrendsClick(title);
    }
});
```

});

Any ideas what I can add to prevent this error ?

Comment: Are you using the v10 version of the webtrends tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that we have to do two things to avoid the "Aborted" error.

1) use setTimeout
2) use mousedown - Especially for FireFox, because it views click as both mousedown and mouseup

```
    $("#someBtn").live("mousedown", function(){
    var mT7 = setTimeout("myFunction()", 50); // 1000 would be a second
});

var myFunction = function(){
var wtArgs = ['WT.dcs_id', 'youridgoeshere', 'DCSext.myFirstVar', varArray[varArray.length-2], 'DCSext.mySecondVar', varArray[varArray.length-1], 'DCSext.myThirdVar', tempArr[0]];
    dcsMultiTrack.apply(this, wtArgs);
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Oooh, seems like this helped me a lot... still testing :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

According to the answers posted here:
[Google Analytics: delay needed for tracking link clicks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611899/google-analytics-delay-needed-for-tracking-link-clicks) , using a delay seems to be the most indicated solution to ensure that GA request is finished before a new page is loaded, as a result of clicking on a link.

I also had this problem: all my clicks were generating a NS_BINDING_ABORTED in HTTPFox, until I modified the code as suggested there. Since then, everything worked fine