# Tag parameters only come through on new tab

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using Google Analytics via Google Tag Manager. I'm on Chrome and checking tags using Google Tag Assistant.

I've noticed that for many, if not most of the events I have tagged, the parameters will not pass through unless the link or key webpage they are clicking on opens in a new tab.

In [HttpFox](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/) the result is a *NS_BINDING_ERROR* or something along those lines.

For example, if you [visit this site](http://trashswag.com), you can see there are two means of navigating to the "submit report" page - the CTA on the top right and in the main nav. I'd like to understand how the CTA performs compared to the main nav so have set up events, but the event only fires if I open the links in new tabs.

What does this error mean and what should I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the ns binding error, have the onclick return false - [Documentation Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624941/ns-binding-aborted-javascript-window-location-replace).

In regards to the event not getting passed, I'm seeing in httpfox that the tid (on the event) is UA-34035531-[1-6]. That doesn't look quite right. How are you setting the account id?

Comment: thanks adding return false has done the trick. As for the [1-6] it's a riddle. I added it, expecting it not to work except it kind of is working. The ID UA-34035531-[1-6] is for 1 master site and 5 subdomains. In GA for these subdomains I've added separate views. Thing is - it works for UA-34035531-2 - the master view. I still pick up events. Why?!

Comment: Yikes! just checked that and adding return false broke my links. I aded return false at the end of the function - it was the last line of script before the final })

Comment: I forgot you weren't doing it on an inline onclick. I found this article on SO - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794197/jquery-analytics-tracking-onclick-ns-binding-aborted]. I haven't tested, but looks promising.

Comment: for your interest a friend gave me some advise on this. IN Goog-Tag-Manager I created a new rule event = gtm.dom and applied it to all link click events. It certainly solves the problem in a neat way. I'm told "this means it won't fire any GA events/pvs unless the DOM elements have been loaded"

Comment: So this solves your ns binding error? I'm not seeing anything fire on the Submit a Report button.

Comment: In httpfox the binding error shows but in Google Tag Assistant and in real time analytics the events are being picked up :-/