# Analytics Events Tracking not working

Tags: google-analytics

We are using analytics on our website wplegion.com. Analytics is working fine, but the event tracking isn't working. Plz see the same code we are using on our website:

```
<input id="changesubmittxt_8" type="submit" value="Proceed" class="submitButton" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Skyler', 'Download', 'Free']);">
```

Can you please help us correct the problem, that maybe causing this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086587/track-event-in-google-analytics-upon-clicking-form-submit

Answer (score 0):

What's the page you're testing? Try capitalizing the C in onClick?