# How to Send / Create Google Analytics Event for Wordpress User Registrations / Logins

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

This seems like it should be a rather important use case for GA events but I really couldn't find any instruction on the net.

I'd like to create an event for any new registrations on my Wordpress site.  If I can append that to logins as well, even better but the former is more important.

I also use WooCommerce so I'd need to ensure registration through that code path is included as well.

I'm familiar enough with adding the GA event code, I'm just not sure where to place it in this instance.  I feel as if this functionality should be baked into the platform or most plugins.  Maybe it is.

I noticed the 'Google Analytics for Wordpress' plugin has a checkbox for adding tracking code to registration pages however I'm not sure what exactly that does on the GA side?  Does it create events?  Is this whole question therefore pointless?

Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*I noticed the 'Google Analytics for Wordpress' plugin has a checkbox for adding tracking code to registration pages however I'm not sure what exactly that does on the GA side? Does it create events? Is this whole question therefore pointless?*

From what I remember, by checking that box you create a custom variable for Logged In Status. By creating a custom variable, you can then create segments off of that and look to see how logged in users use the site compared to non-logged in users.

However, if you simply want to track new registrations, you could add GA event tracking to the submit button when the user submits the registration form.

If I were you, I'd do both.

Comment: I'll check that variable, thanks.  Is there a better hook than on the submit button?  What if they miss a required field and hit the button twice?  Will that count as two?

Comment: Right, you'd want to send the event upon successful completion of the form. There are a few ways you could do that, but I would use [hitCallback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086587/track-event-in-google-analytics-upon-clicking-form-submit).

Answer (score 0):

If there is a page they land on after registering then just register that page as a goal in GA. I get your intent behind registering it as an event, but it might be easier to just do it as a goal.