# Analytics _trackEvent in jQuery AJAX on success before redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, tracking

I am trying to track event on success of $.ajax function and then redirect the page. Unfrotunatly the tracking wont appear on analytics and I belive this is because my redirect wont let the tracking finish it's job. I heard I can detect when data is passed to google analytics but could not figure it out.

```
$.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : formActionAttr,
                data : datastring,
                success : function() {                                                                                          

                    //analytics tracking                                        
                    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category 1', 'Success', formActionAttr]);                                                    

                    window.location.href = pdfurl;                                                                      

                }

                });
```

appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Google Analytic's [hitCallback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086587/track-event-in-google-analytics-upon-clicking-form-submit):

```
success: function(){
    _gaq.push(['_set','hitCallback',function(){

        window.location.href = pdfurl;

    }]);

    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Category 1','Success',formActionAttr]);

}
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try it out tomorrow as I am away right now from my place. I will certainly accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: unfortunately that seems not to work. There are no errors in console but it wont make redirect.

Comment: I belive this is because I use new analytics code with ga.js, is there any difference?

Comment: You have an error in '_hitCallback' it should be 'hitCallback'

Comment: Documentation :) https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#hitCallback