# Page views are tracking, but events and custom vars are not

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to track a user logging in with GA. I have my custom_var code occuring onClick of the login button.

```
<input type="submit" formtarget="_blank" onClick="_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Users Login', '$("#user_login").val());', 3]);"/>
```

"#user_login" is the field containing the information I need passed.

I am using the formtarget attribute to open in a new window. This was after thinking that maybe the onClick event was not running before the page was being redirected.

This custom event is not being tracked when I log in to the account, but page views are. At first, I thought there was an issue with my code, so I tried tracking a regular event on click of an anchor:

```
<a href="/about-us/about-discovery-capital/" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Testing', 'Click', 'About']);">About</a>
```

The same issue occured, page views are fine, but the event is not tracking.

- The GA code that I am using is up to date and in the correct place.
- The site is password protected, but as the page views are being
  tracked I dont see this as an issue.
- I have run the GA debugger chrome extention, but I am getting no
  errors

Unfortunately due to the client, I cannot provide the website.

If you could shed light on what possible reasons there could be for page views tracking, but not events, would be a great help!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Open Firefox and download the [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) plugin. Click your links with the events on them. Are they showing up red and saying aborted? If so, you're running into an issue where the event/custom variable isn't given enough time to fire the event before the next page loads, thus aborting the request.

The solution: [hitCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086587/track-event-in-google-analytics-upon-clicking-form-submit/12461558#12461558)

The hitCallback function will let send your visitor to the next page once it receives the callback from Google Analytics saying the event has been received.

I wrote an article on how to use it inline, like in your case. You can check that out here - [When to use hitCallback](http://www.swellpath.com/2013/12/universal-analytics-using-hitcallback/).

Comment: Thanks Blexy. I have run HTTPFox but no errors are returned. The only corresponding GA feedback given is this line: GET http://www.google-analytics.com/collect [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 33ms]. Should I attempt hitCallback or does this mean that isnt the issue!?

Comment: By the way, that is a very well written article. Very easy to understand and follow. Much appreciated.

Comment: If you're getting a 200 OK, then you're ok. Are you seeing the event show up in real-time reports?

Comment: Ah, I think I just realized what the issue is... in order to set a custom variable, you have send it along with a pageview or an event - more info [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#setup)

Comment: I have added the _trackEvent snippet. When I look at the Real-Time reports, it states there is 1 visitor active, which is good, but under Events on the same page, the view is empty

Comment: So when you click the About link, there is no event showing up in the real-time reports? Can you take a picture of the request getting sent?

Comment: No, no events showing up in the real-time reports. How can I get a screenshot of the request for you? Are you referring to the Network tab information?

Comment: Hey @roryWolf, shoot me an email and we can talk there - nicholasblexrud@gmail.com