# Google Analytics _gaq.push not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've a very basic tracking event tied to my login button that's working correctly in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox (v26)

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Navigation', 'Log In', 'Log In button']);
```

When a user clicks the login button, their request is authenticated via an Ajax call to the server, if the server responds with a success message, then the this GA code is triggered.

No error is reported to the console.

Is there a way to find out if the code fired correctly? Or to know if `_gaq` has initialised correctly?

Comment: Does real-time reporting in Analytics show anything going on when you fire the event?

Comment: Nothing shows in the real time report when in Firefox, in Chrome/IE I can see the event

Comment: Is there a redirect taking place once the request is authenticated?

Comment: Yes, the basic flow is User click -> $.ajax -> success{ _gaq.push(); someLogic(); redirect; }

Comment: check this out: https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting. Maybe download Live http headers for firefox to see what's happening.

Comment: Sometimes the redirect is taking place before the tracking event has actually loaded. Try adding a slight delay before redirecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Google Analytics built-in [hitCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086587/track-event-in-google-analytics-upon-clicking-form-submit) function:

So, on success:

```
_gaq.push(['_set', 'hitCallback' , function(){
 //default action
}]);

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Navigation', 'Log In', 'Log In button']);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've more than one tracker which complicates things. (_gaq.push(['b._trackEvent'... etc.) So if I need to use things like _gaq.push(['b._set','hitCallback'... then the original setTimeout solution is better for me I think even though yours is a better answer to the question

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Boaz I introduced a delay (50ms) after the GA code fires.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Navigation', 'Log In', 'Log In button']);

var timeout = 1;
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1)
    timeout = 50;

setTimeout(function() {
    //redirect
}, timeout);
```

Event then fired correctly

Comment: Now that you've debugged the issue, @Blexy method seems to be the most reliable way to overcome it.