# Add delay to Google Analytics e-Commerce Tracking

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I am successfully using the following snippet to add a delay to my Google Analytics event tracking...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function trackOutboundLink(form, category, action, label) {
try {
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category , action, label]);
} catch(err){}
  setTimeout(function() {
    form.submit();
  }, 100);
}
</script>
```

This has solved the problems I was experiencing with certain events only tracking randomly.  I am know facing similar issue but with my e-commerce analytics.

Is there a similar snippet I can use to add a delay to that as well?

Comment: Have you tried using Universal analytics i know its still beta but i have found it more stable then the old tracking methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should really use Google Analytics [hitCallback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086587/track-event-in-google-analytics-upon-clicking-form-submit).

So, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function trackOutboundLink(form, category, action, label) {
    try {
        _gaq.push(['_set', 'hitCallback', function(){
            form.submit();
        }]);

        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category , action, label]);
    } catch(e){} 
}
</script>
```

*This code is untested, but you should get the idea.