# Google-Analytics: Event track form action

Tags: javascript, forms, events, google-analytics

I want to use a Google Analytics-event like this:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'Home Contact']);"
```

when the following form action is fired:

```
<form action="http://webshop-cs.tecdoc.net/sonnak/?user=sonnakno&pass=sonnakno&articleCountry=NO" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input id="submit" src="http://www.sonnak.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/lv2.jpg" type="image" value="submit"/> 
</form>
```

Any idea how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Track event in google analytics upon clicking form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086587/track-event-in-google-analytics-upon-clicking-form-submit)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

```
<form action="http://webshop-cs.tecdoc.net/sonnak/?user=sonnakno&pass=sonnakno&articleCountry=NO" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input id="submit" src="http://www.sonnak.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/lv2.jpg" type="image" value="submit" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'Home Contact']);"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: Google updated their methods. You should look at their new way of doing things: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Answer (score 0):

Can i recommend you this jQuery plugin (i'm the author). Will be easy to setup  the Event Tracking for Google Analytics with it:

https://github.com/DiegoZoracKy/google-analytics-event-tracking.

With this plugin, your code to track this form submit would be:

```
$.googleAnalyticsEventTracking({
    targetSelector: 'form[action="http://webshop-cs.tecdoc.net/sonnak/?user=sonnakno&pass=sonnakno&articleCountry=NO"]', // I suggest you give an ID (e.g. home-contact) to this form and then use #home-contact instead of lookup for the action attribute
    events: {
        eventType: 'submit',
        gaEventData: {
            category: 'Forms',
            action: 'Submit', 
            label: 'Home Contact'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the updated Google Analytics tracking code in your header?
Should look like this:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Use the new format for tracking events:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event',  'Category', 'Action')"
```

The `send` and `event` values you can't change, without them the script won't send anything to Google Analytics. The `Catergoy` and `Action` values are required, you can give them any name you want. For `Action` I would recommend `click`, that's the action you're registering with `onclick`. You can even add more optional parameters if you need to.

Your code could look something like this:

```
<form action="http://webshop-cs.tecdoc.net/sonnak/?user=sonnakno&pass=sonnakno&articleCountry=NO" method="post" target="_blank">
   <input id="submit" src="http://www.sonnak.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/lv2.jpg" type="image" value="submit" onclick="ga('send', 'event',  'Form', 'click')";"/> 
</form>
```