# Google Analytics Event Tracking through onclick button

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to track on how many people is clicking the button and sessions will be collected in Google Analytics. However, the I cannot get any result in Google Analytics Events. 
My code is below:

```
<script>
          function handleOutboundLinkClicks(event) {
  ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: 'Outbound Link',
    eventAction: 'click',
    eventLabel: event.target.href,
    transport: 'beacon'
  });
}

      </script>
```

////
The code for my button is below:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Validate and Submit" onclick=”_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’, ‘form, ‘submit’, ’order sent’, 10]);”/>
```

Then entire code for this page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Keepsake Florals</title>
    <!--link to external css file-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="keepsakeflorals.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ksform.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
   <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>




      <script>

      function handleOutboundLinkClicks(event) {
  ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: 'Outbound Link',
    eventAction: 'click',
    eventLabel: event.target.href,
    transport: 'beacon'
  });
}

      </script>



</head>
<body>

<div id="box">
<h1><a href="index.html" title="click here to return home"> KEEPSAKE FLORALS </a> </h1>
</div>

<div>
<nav id="mainnav"> 
<a href="index.html"> Home</a> |
<a href="aboutus.html"> About Us  </a> |
<a href="flowers.html"> Flowers </a> |
<a href="order.html"> Order </a> |
<a href="review.html"> Review </a> |
</nav>
</div>



<form action="thankyou.html" id="contact-form">

  <fieldset id="contactinfo">
  <legend> <span> Contact Information </span> </legend>
    <label> 
    Name
    <input type="text" name="name" id="nameinput" placeholder="First and last name"  />
    </label>
      <label>
      Email
      <input type="email" name="email" id="emailinput" placeholder="address@example.com" />
      </label>
      <label>
      Phone
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phoneinput" placeholder="phone number" />
      </label>

     </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="orderflower">
          <legend> <span> Flowers to order </span> </legend> 
          <label for="mother" >
             <input type="radio" name="flower" id="mother" value="mother" checked="checked"  />
             Mother's day flower 
             </label>
                 <label for="father">
                         <input type="radio" name="flower" id="father" value="father" />
                        Fathers day flower
             </label>
                     <label for="otheroccasion">
                    <input type="radio" name="flower" id="occasion" value="occasion"  />
                    Other occasion flower
                            </label>

             <label for="valentinesday">
                 <input type="radio" name="flower" id="vday" value="vday" />
                  Valentine's Day
                  </label>

             <label for="others">
                <input type="radio" name="flower" id="others" value="others"  />
                  Others

                  <input type="text" name="other" id="otherinput">
                  </label>    
              </fieldset>
          <fieldset id="delivery">
          <legend> <span> How to contact you ? </span> </legend>
          <label for "question">
              <input type="radio" name="flower" id="phone"  />
                 Via my handphone number
                 </label>
                  <label for "question">
              <input type="radio" name="flower" id="email"  />
                 Via my email
                 </label>


          </fieldset>
          <fieldset id="helpneeded" >

          <legend> <span> Any help needed? </span> </legend> 
          <textarea id="helpneeded" name="helpneeded" rows="4" cols="20"> </textarea>
          </fieldset>    
           <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Validate and Submit" onclick=”ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit', 'order sent', 10);”/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Track event in google analytics upon clicking form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086587/track-event-in-google-analytics-upon-clicking-form-submit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong:

1. You're mixing the deprecated classic GA syntax with the new Universal Analytics syntax. UA does not use the `_gaq` object anymore. Your `onclick` code should be:

   ```
   ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit', 'order sent', 10);
   ```

   Note that you also had a mix of smart quote and straight quotes. You should just use straight quotes.
2. You've defined a function `handleOutboundLinkClicks` that doesn't seem to correlate with the button, so you won't see the `Outbound link` event when you click your button.

But for all intents and purposes, the code I posted should work for your button, if that's your main concern.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I am not so sure why it is still not working for this event tracking. I have updated my code on top for the page.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late, but I hope this would help someone who lands on this question.

Your issue is most likely because the Google Analytics Javascript code stops execution once your form gets submitted and loads a new page (`thankyou.html`). You have two options:

1. Use the `transport` property and set its value to `beacon`:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit', 'order sent', 10, {
    transport: 'beacon'
});
```

2. For browsers that do not support the `beacon` transport method, you can use a callback function:

In your HTML, modify your submit button (remove the `onclick` attribute):

```
<input  type="submit" id="submit" value="Validate and Submit" />
```

Then, add an event listener to this submit button:

```
var form = document.getElementById('contact-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the form from submitting immediately

    //Send the event to Google Analytics, and then manually
    //submit the form
    ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit', 'order sent', 10, {
            hitCallback: function() {
                form.submit(); //submit the form now
            }
    });
});
```

References:

1. [Outbound link and form tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#outbound_link_and_form_tracking)
2. [Knowing when the hit has been sent](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#hitcallback)