# Onclick Button Event Tracking for Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I want to track when a button has been clicked on. I have tried multiple ways of doing this and nothing shows up in my Google Analytics. What am I doing wrong?

```
<a href="#Reserve" class="btn-large btn-primary text-white" onClick="ga([ '_trackEvent', 'button', 'click', 'reserve now' ]);" >RESERVE NOW<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-right"></span></a>
```

Comment: <a href="#Reserve" class="btn-large btn-primary text-white" onClick="ga([ '_trackEvent', 'button', 'click', 'reserve now' ]);" >RESERVE NOW<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right pull-right"></span></a>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Track event in google analytics upon clicking form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086587/track-event-in-google-analytics-upon-clicking-form-submit)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'type_here_your_category_event', 'type_here_your_event_name');" href="#">Hit here</a>
```

For buttons it's work as well.

```
<button onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'type_here_your_category_event', 'type_here_your_event_name');">Hit here</button>
```

`type_here_your_category_event` - just type here your cat name
`type_here_your_event_name` - detail name of event,
`send` & `event` - live as is.

It depends on which button you want to hook this event.

Please see [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) from Google Analytics Docs

Comment: has google tags removed all of the "older" event tracking with this method of adding it to an a link?