# Google Analytics: Is _gaq.push() a blocking function?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

What I am trying to do is to redirect the user to the next page right after sending an event to Google Analytics:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'xxx' ...]);
window.location = 'some url ...';
```

The above code manages to register events because I can see them in the GA report. However I suspect that *some* events were lost because the browser redirects the user to the new page *before* the track pixel loads.

My questions are:

1. Does _gaq.push() block until the event has successfully reached Google's server?
2. If not, what is the best way to make achieve what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427580/race-condition-and-using-google-analytics-asynchronous-gaq-synchronously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my observation based on some quick research. That function is part of Google Analytic's asynchronous API, so it should not block anything, otherwise, it's not async. :)

Digging through the obfuscated ga.js, you can kinda see that the tracking is probably called onbeforeunload, which fires when you leave a page.

It really doesn't matter if the tracking pixel loads completely, it's a fire & forget. As long as the request is initiated and reaches Google's server, it'll get tracked. The response (in this case, the pixel image) is a by-product.

Comment: Uhm, no ? 1) "push" is native javascript, the only google specific thing here is the name of the array to which the data is added. And the image request is not a byproduct, it is the data that is sent to google. That's why Google suggests to add a timeout before a redirect or, with Universal Analytics, to use hit callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a [support page](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=-3ruoay554a9h&cbrank=2) that says you might want to add a delay after calling `_gac.push`, however they claim that this is to give the Google Analytics JavaScript a chance to *load*. They don't say that it's to ensure the request is sent.

> **First, delay the outbound click by a fraction of a second.**
>
> This delay will hardly be noticeable by the user, but it will provide the browser more time load the tracking code. Without this method, it's possible that a user can click on the outbound link before the tracking code loads, in which case the event will not be recorded.

I haven't checked @pixelfreak's claim of handling `onbeforeunload`, but it seems that's what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this method, but I have not tried

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'xxx' ...]);
_gaq.push(function(){location.reload()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use 1 sec delay. Like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'xxx' ...]);
setTimeout(function(){window.location = 'some_url'}, 1000);
```